# How to improve my LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

The following query does solve my problem however it seems overly complex.

The problem is I have a table that stores menu options (id, name, description and price). I also have a session variable that stores the users selections in a Dictionary (storing id and quantity).

The LINQ I've produced below basically calculates the value of everything summed up. It converts the table to a dictionary and then sums the prices multiplied by the quantity.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
var prices = _db.MenuOptions
                .Select(o => new { o.Id, o.Price })
                .ToDictionary(o => o.Id, o => o.Price);
Session["price"] = prices
              .Where(p => orderItems.Keys.Contains((int)p.Key))
              .Sum(p => p.Value * orderItems[p.Key]);
```

Comment: That looks ok to me, I've seen way more exotic constructions around here.

Comment: What is `_db`? Are you using an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate?

Comment: _db is using EntityFramework yes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code, rather than solving an actual problem. I think it would go down well at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll post review stuff there in future. My question seems to have been answered here though. Thanks.

Comment: The original code is not bad, because it loads only the required columns. Most answers here load all options objects even though only the price for the ordered items is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select` part is unnessecary and can be dropped:

```
var prices = _db.MenuOptions.ToDictionary(o => o.Id, o => o.Price);
```

And the `price` calculation could start from the `orderItems`:

```
Session["price"] = orderItems.Sum(oi => oi.Value * prices[oi.Key]);
```

(Assuming all `orderItems` have a price in the db.)

**Edit:** Going from Arcturus answer, something like this might also be possible for a "one-liner" but is probably slower (see comments):

```
Session["price"] = orderItems.Sum(oi => oi.Value * _db.MenuOptions.Single(o => o.ID == oi.Key).Price);
```

Comment: Much more succinctly put than mine with the added bonus of simplifying the first part too (I'm embarrassed I missed that simple optimisation).

Comment: The one-liner will loop through all the options for each order item. It's not the same as the original and performs worse. If `_db` is an ORM you'll even end up executing multiple queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Clarified that.

Comment: Another problem is that you are loading _all_ fields for all options, even though only the options for the ordered items are required. The `select` part is required to load only the prices and IDs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you mean only the one-liner? And I would think LINQ is smarter than that, but maybe not ...

Comment: Both versions have this issue. LINQ is the query API, not the implementation. Each provider maps a LINQ query to its underlying language. LINQ's `Select()` maps to a SQL `SELECT` statement while `ToDictionary()` has no equivalent and simply enumerates the IQueryable, loading the entire object.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. That's what I get for using almost only `LINQ to Objects`.

Answer (score 3):

One immediate thing that springs to mind is looping over `orderItems.Keys` instead of `prices` and then filtering them by key.

Assuming orderItems is a standard dictionary then it implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. This means we can do something like:

```
Session["price"] = orderItems.Sum(x=>x.Value*prices[x.Key]);
```

You could probably make it all into one query by doing joins but personally I would suspect that it is much more readable this way.

The reason this is better apart from being briefer and more readable is that your original method will loop over all of the price dictionary when it only needs a very limited number of elements from there. In fact only the elements that match orderItems. Therefore it makes much more sense to order over the smaller list when we know we want all items.

This will only potentially fail if an item in the orderItems dictionary doesn't have a corresponding entry in the prices Dictionary but I assume that should never happen. If it does though you'll need to guard appropriately.

Comment: This might not work if the orderItems might contain more items than the prices.

Comment: @Arcturus: I've just added a note about that. I would assume from context that this shouldn't happen (I assume this is an ecommerce type situation where orderItems are selected from products which all have prices) but it is certainly well worth raising.

Comment: Very true.. What is weird, is that the example is parsing the prices from the menuitems, instead of using database values.

Comment: @Arcturus: indeed. I wasn't going to start wondering about that. :)

Comment: Maybe menu options here mean meals at a restaurant or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the original code is not bad, because it loads ONLY the required columns, although it does this for all menu options.

A better solution is to load from the database only the prices for the ordered items:

```
var prices = _db.MenuOptions
                .Where(o => orderItems.Keys.Contains(o.Id))
                .Select(o => new { o.Id, o.Price })
                .ToDictionary(o => o.Id, o => o.Price);

Session["price"] = orderItems.Sum(oi => oi.Value * prices[oi.Key]);
```

The `Select` statement ensures only ID and Price are loaded and can't be removed.
The `Where` statement will create a `WHERE ID IN (....)` clause, returning only prices for the order items.

Comment: In this case, `prices` and `orderItems` should have the same length and it is not important from which you start the price calculation. So for minimal change from the original code you would only have to move the `Where()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Why first create an anonymous class, and put the stuff in a Dictionary, when you can use the data directly?

```
Session["price"] = _db.MenuOptions
               .Where(p => orderItems.Keys.Contains((int)p.Id))
               .Sum(p => p.Price * orderItems[p.Id]);
```

Comment: This may not compile, depending on what `_db` is. If it's an ORM like EF, it may complain that it can't translate `orderItems[p.Id]` to SQL

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that it's using EntityFramework hence I pulled the data into Business Logic first.